# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.android.server.fingerprint.ClientMonitor.getOwnerString()' on a null object reference

Tags: android, android-9.0-pie, android-fingerprint-api, android-biometric

Getting this exception in Crashlytics reports last few weeks. Android P only.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.NullPointerException
Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.android.server.fingerprint.ClientMonitor.getOwnerString()' on a null object reference
android.os.Parcel.createException (Parcel.java:1948)
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1910)
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1860)
android.app.IActivityManager$Stub$Proxy.activityPaused (IActivityManager.java:4003)
android.app.servertransaction.PauseActivityItem.postExecute (PauseActivityItem.java:63)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState (TransactionExecutor.java:161)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute (TransactionExecutor.java:72)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1800)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6649)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:493)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:826)

Caused by android.os.RemoteException
Remote stack trace: at com.android.server.fingerprint.FingerprintService$5.onTaskStackChanged(FingerprintService.java:237) at com.android.server.am.TaskChangeNotificationController.lambda$new$0(TaskChangeNotificationController.java:70) at com.android.server.am.-$$Lambda$TaskChangeNotificationController$kftD881t3KfWCASQEbeTkieVI2M.accept(Unknown Source:0) at com.android.server.am.TaskChangeNotificationController.forAllLocalListeners(TaskChangeNotificationController.java:263) at com.android.server.am.TaskChangeNotificationController.notifyTaskStackChanged(TaskChangeNotificationController.java:276)
```

Any ideas/workarounds?

Comment: I have same issue both unfortunately I didn't find a clue beside this question. @toxa_xa Have you ever figured it out?

Comment: @sela unfortunately no, but now it dissapeared from my craslytics report